# GetField const in type's base class

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I use reflection in .NET 4 to get field info for a base class from a derived class?

For instance,

```
class Parent
{
    public const bool ParentField = true;
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public const bool ChildField = true;
}
```

Using those classes:

```
Console.WriteLine(p.GetType().GetField("ParentField"));
Console.WriteLine(c.GetType().GetField("ChildField"));
Console.WriteLine(c.GetType().GetField("ParentField"));
```

The third line doesn't work the way I expect.  `GetField` returns null when getting a field from the base type.  I have tried the overload of `GetField` with all the different `BindingsFlags` values I can think of, but it always returns null.

**EDIT**

I should have been clear that this

```
c.GetType().GetField("ParentField",BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
```

also returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the inherited constants you have to be a little more specific with your binding flags:

```
c.GetType().GetField("ParentField", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
```

Comment: @hmqcnoesy It works on my machine and [here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/8Vp3Vg)... What is your complete test code?